# Notification for high vCPU Usage

Tags: monitoring, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vcpu

At the moment I'm using a third party tool (vmturbo) which allows me to monitor the vCPU usage on my VMs. I've been wondering however if there's any method built inside of VMware or through powerCLI which would allow myself to be notified if there was ever any saturation or high vCPU utilization.

Is there anyway inside of vSphere to get notifications whenever vCPU utilization or saturation is at a certain threshold? For example, say that a VM reaches above 80% vCPU I would get some kind of notification the moment any VM reaches that threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. vSphere has configurable alarms you can use. Without rehashing their already excellent guide, see [this article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018029) on VMware for details on how to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. There are already a slew of built-in alarms in vCenter. You can edit the alarms at the parent level and add a number of actions.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set [vSphere Server Alarms.](http://vmfocus.com/2012/08/12/setting-up-configuring-alarms-in-vcenter-5-part-1/) You can set all different types of triggers, and apply them globally.